# Apache PHP no longer working after upgrading to 19.10 from 19.04

Tags: apache2, php, 19.04, 19.10

I updated my Ubuntu from 19.04 to 19.10. Now the Apache PHP is not working. All I get is the raw PHP code instead of the rendered PHP. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgraded the other day and found the same issue today when I went to start writing some PHP. My solution was this:

```
sudo apt update; sudo apt remove php -y; sudo apt remove apache2 -y; sudo apt autoremove -y
```

This will uninstall apache2 and php, then we need to reinstall:

```
sudo apt install apache2 -y; sudo apt install php -y;
```

Then you are going to need to enable php (this may be the only step you need to do)

```
sudo a2enmod php7.x
```

*Note X is for your version of PHP (As of my writing installing php will install 7.3).
Also note that you may not need to uninstall apache2/php and then reinstall. This is how I did it before I enabled PHP again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex. That fixed it! :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue I just ran `sudo a2enmod php7.3` and it worked.